# Custom SQLitePlugin Remote iOS Build 404 error

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I have written a VS Cordova Tools App and I'm having trouble when trying to build to iOS when the SQLitePlugin is installed. (404 not found com.brodysoft.sqlitePlugin)

When I un-install the SQLitePlugin and build with only the com.msopentech.websql it builds successfully , but then the localStorage on my Android device does not work when I build for Android.

This forces me to install sqlLitePlugin when building for Android and un-installing it when building for iOS.

Could someone please assist if they had any similar issues and know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

## Custom Solution

I found the solution, there was no package.json or .fetch.json files in the com.brodysoft.sqlitePlugin directory and

I had to create the files and put the extracted repo with the files in the plugman cache directory "C:\Users\Username.plugman\cache\com.brodysoft.sqlitePlugin" then the build from VS Cordova Tools could see the plugin.

## .fetch.json

```
{"source":    {"type":"local","path":"C:\\Users\\Username\\.plugman\\cache\\com.brodysoft.sqlitePlugin\\1.0.3\\package"}}
```

## package.json

```
{
"version": "1.0.3",
"name": "com.brodysoft.sqlitePlugin",
"cordova_name": "SQLitePlugin",
"description": "SQLitePlugin for Apache Cordova",
"license": "Apache 2.0",
"repo": "https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.git",
"issue": "https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin/issues",
"keywords": [
    "cordova",
    " sqlite",
    " db",
    " database"
],
"platforms": ["ios","android",
    "wp8",
    "windows8",
    "windows"
],
"engines": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically when this happens, you just have to clean your solution before building to iOS.  This kind of issue happens so often that I have become accustomed to cleaning my solution every single time I build as sort of a second nature.

Comment: Hi c0r3yz thank you! I've tried cleaning the solution multiple times ,but the build still failed I posted a solution that worked for me below.